# AndroidにてFatal Signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1,

Tags: android, java, webview

BaseAdapterに、独自のフィルター機能を付け加えたAdapterにフィルターを掛けると以下のエラーが発生してクラッシュしてしまいます。
具体的なクラッシュ箇所は明示されませんが、ログを見る限り、WebViewがあやしいのか？と勘ぐりたくなりますが、アプリ内でのWebViewの使用箇所はありません。

以下のログは私のアプリケーション内のログです。

> 06-07 22:28:33.778: W/art(9064): static void art::Dbg::DdmSendHeapSegments(bool) unimplemented Not counting objects in space SpaceTypeImageSpace begin=0x6f4da000,end=0x6fe4ea88,size=9MB,name="/data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.art"]
>   06-07 22:28:33.779: W/art(9064): static void art::Dbg::DdmSendHeapSegments(bool) unimplemented Not counting objects in space SpaceTypeZygoteSpace begin=0x72e29000,end=0x745ae000,size=23MB,name="Zygote space"]
>   06-07 22:28:33.821: D/BoardListAdapter(9064): setFilterItems
>   06-07 22:28:33.961: W/google-breakpad(9064): ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
>   06-07 22:28:33.961: W/google-breakpad(9064): Chrome build fingerprint:
>   06-07 22:28:33.961: W/google-breakpad(9064): 1.0
>   06-07 22:28:33.961: W/google-breakpad(9064): 1
>   06-07 22:28:33.961: W/google-breakpad(9064): 92675e2e-3e24-4fdd-9bc9-d979deace950
>   06-07 22:28:33.961: W/google-breakpad(9064): ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
>   06-07 22:28:33.961: E/chromium(9064): ### WebView Version 43.0.2357.121 (code 2357121)
>   06-07 22:28:33.962: A/libc(9064): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 9064 (****.********)

フィルター機能は、以下のようになっています。
BaseAdapterを継承したクラス

```
private ArrayList<BoardItem> mOriginalList;//元データ
private ArrayList<BoardItem> mFilterdlList;//フィルターを適用したデータ
private ArrayList<BoardItem> mPublishList;//表示するデータ
private ArrayList<FilterItem> mFilterList;//フィルターデータ

public void setData(Collection<? extends BoardItem> data) {

    synchronized (mLock) {
        mOriginalList.clear();
        mOriginalList.addAll(data);
        filter();
    }

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void clear() {
    synchronized (mLock) {
        mOriginalList.clear();
        filter();
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void addAll(Collection<? extends BoardItem> items) {
    synchronized (mLock) {
        mOriginalList.addAll(items);
        filter();
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

/**
 * FilterItemをアダプターにセットして、フィルターを反映させます
 * 
 * @param filterItems
 */
public void setFilterItems(ArrayList<FilterItem> filterItems) {
    Log.d(TAG, "setFilterItems");
    synchronized (mLock) {
        mFilterList.clear();
        mFilterList.addAll(filterItems);
        filter();
    }

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

/**
 * FilterItemをアダプターにセットして、フィルターを反映させます
 * 
 * @param filterItems
 */
public void addFilterItem(FilterItem filter) {
    Log.d(TAG, "addFilterItem");
    synchronized (mLock) {
        mFilterList.clear();
        mFilterList.add(filter);
        filter();
    }

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

/**
 * 時間制約(公開一秒前)によるフィルタリングを行います
 */
private void filterByTime() {
    // 時間制限によるフィルター
    ArrayList<BoardItem> filterdList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<BoardItem> copyList = null;

    copyList = new ArrayList<>(mFilterdlList);

    for (Iterator<BoardItem> ite = copyList.iterator(); ite.hasNext();) {
        BoardItem boardItem = (BoardItem) ite.next();
        // 現在の日時
        Calendar nowcal = Calendar.getInstance();
        // 比較対象日時
        Calendar dateCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        try {
            dateCal.setTime(mSimpleDateFormat.parse(boardItem.getPublishDate()));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // long型の差分（ミリ秒）
        long diffTime = nowcal.getTimeInMillis() - dateCal.getTimeInMillis();
        if (diffTime > -1000) {
            filterdList.add(boardItem);
        }
    }
    mPublishList = filterdList;
}

/**
 * フィルター作業を行います
 */
private void filter() {

    ArrayList<FilterItem> filterList = null;

    filterList = new ArrayList<>(mFilterList);

    if (filterList.size() == 0) {
        mFilterdlList = new ArrayList<>(mOriginalList);
        filterByTime();
        return;
    }

    ArrayList<BoardItem> filterdList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<BoardItem> copyList = null;

    copyList = new ArrayList<>(mOriginalList);

    BoardItem: for (Iterator<BoardItem> ite = copyList.iterator(); ite.hasNext();) {
        BoardItem item = (BoardItem) ite.next();
        for (Iterator<FilterItem> iteFilter = filterList.iterator(); iteFilter.hasNext();) {
            FilterItem filterItem = (FilterItem) iteFilter.next();
            if (filterItem.isSelected()) {
                if (filterItem.match(item.get(filterItem.getGroupName()))) {
                    filterdList.add(item);
                    break BoardItem;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    mFilterdlList = filterdList;

    filterByTime();
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

自己解決いたしました。

```
filterItem.match(item.get(filterItem.getGroupName()))
```

内部では、PatternクラスからMattcherを生成して、メンバ変数にもたせていましたが、それが原因のようです。都度Mattcherを生成するようにしたところ、Fatal Signal Errorはでなくなりました。